# ${getText(fieldName)} shows nothing in client validation

Tags: java, validation, struts2, resourcebundle, ognl

I have implemented client side validation mechanism using Struts2 framework, but when an error occurred  `${getText(fieldName)}` variable present in properties file appears empty, for example, it appears `"The field is required"` instead of `"The field username is required"`

I have this in properties file:

```
errors.required=Field ${getText(fieldName)} is required.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just define the key value pare in the properties file

```
username=username
```

assumed that `username` is a `fieldName` in the `-validation.xml`